# Export virtual fields in attribute table to Excel using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, export, excel

I am using QGIS.

I am trying to export my attribute table to Excel but I want the virtual fields also to be exported **with their function**. For example I have a field that sums up two other fields and I want in my Excel file to keep the `sum` function and not only the context of the number.

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE. What software are you using?

Comment: I'm using Qgis software

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: keep in mind, that you can't directly translate the QGis Expression to Excel Functions. Even if you find a way to export the fields with the underlaying function, the calculation most likely won't work since the syntax is different.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is there a way I can export only the non-virtual fields into an existing Excel table?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to export your attribute table containing **virtual fields**, just right click on the layer, choose export, then select MS Office Excel format. All attributes will be exported including the virtual fields that you have created. However, the functions from the field calculator cannot be exported as MS. excel formulas.

[image]

Comment: I think that the question was about export  'Virtual Fields' in a normal layer.

Comment: you are right @ValP. I have amended the answer accordingly.